# Angular 4.2.4 + Typescript 2.3.4 + RxJS 5.4.2: "first()" is not a known on Observable (!?!)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

> **edit** See Ikhtiyor's answer as it may fix the TypeScript related issue. My problem came from the fact I forgot to .subscribe and wrote the handler function in .first() directly.

So, facing this error:

```
Property 'first' does not exist on type Observable<{}>
```

I've found discussions where people stuck to the following versions and got their issues fixed:

> Angular 4.2.4 + Typescript  2.3.4 + RxJS 5.4.2

Still, it doesn't work for me. Tested on 2 machines (one mac, one windows). Not even after clearing node_modules and re-npm install'ing them. **Anyone facing this blocker as well?**

Example:

```
const obs = new Observable( observer => {

  setTimeout( () => {
    observer.next(
      [{
        type: 'voting',
        title: 'First dynamic resolution',
        description: 'Issued by dummy web API. Dynamic data rocks.',
        documents: ['a doc'],
        voting:{ 'jem': -1 },
        status: 'PENDING'
      }, {
        type: 'voting',
        title: 'Other dynamic resolution',
        description: 'Issued by dummy web API. We know Jem is proud.',
        documents: ['another doc'],
        voting:{ 'jem': -1 },
        status: 'PENDING'
      }]
    );
  }, 1000);
});

// Compile stops here: Property 'first' does not exist on type Observable<{}>
// Original mistake: it's "obs.first().subscribe(..."
obs.first( data => {
  console.log('data feteched');
});
```

Comment: so.. the code is irrelevant?

Comment: yep, won't compile and Webstorm complains about this. Been using observables for ages and now this enw project claims .first (and other operators / observable properties) aren't known.

Comment: just added an example code fragment

Comment: @Jem have you pulled the typings from the `@types` organisation for rxjs? `npm install --save-dev @types/rx`

Comment: Hi @Fenton, thanks - just added that but doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

You have to import each observable's method or operator like this

for method `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`
for operator `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: Hi@Ikhtiyor, thanks but that didn't work either. It fixes the compile issue, but the ".first()" operator I use doesn't fire at all if imported that way: import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

Comment: Oh wait, seems I skipped chaining "subscribe" to "first", like in .first().subscribe ( (...) => { ... }) ... let me see that

Comment: Ok, been looking like crazy in the wrong place. I forgot the .subscribe chaining. Thanks for your time :-)